# Is there any function for extracting a subtensor using logical index vector?

Tags: matlab, tensor

I have a 4D tensor X(35*35*4*5), 5 is the number of samples, i want to extract the two fisrt samples and the last one using a logical index vector `Ind=[1; 1; 0; 0; 1]`

I've tried using this instruction `X(:,:,:,Ind)` but it returns an error `Size of data does not match specified size of tensor`

Comment: `SubMatrix=X(:,:,:,[1 2 5])` works fine for me ...

Comment: Thank you i changed the logical vector into a vector of indices and it works !

Answer (score 0):

It works, but those are not logical indices:

```
X(:,:,:,[true true false false true])
```

Comment: `Ind` here it's a logical array, this also doesn't work !